# bluebird - promise order when returning another promise

Tags: promise, bluebird

I'm trying to make this code execute the console.logs in order (test1, test2, test3). Now it's test1,test3, test2. I was expecting that the second then() would wait for the resolve() function before starting, but it's not working :)

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

var promise = bluebird.resolve(true);
promise.then(function() {
  return new bluebird(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("test1");

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("test2");
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
});

promise.then(function() {
  console.log("test3");
});
```

http://requirebin.com/?gist=7ba0a8500400bfa7fd22

Comment: You want `promise.then(…).then(…)` - don't invoke the second `then()` on the `promise` itself again, but rather on the return value of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are immutable. They broadcast their value. Once a promise resolves with a value it will have that value forever.

```
var p = Promise.resolve(3);
p.then(() => console.log(1));
p.then(() => console.log(2));
```

In the above example, both will execute *after p resolved* and will not wait for each other. This makes sense because promises are immutable.

You can change the promise reference since `then` returns a new promise:

```
promise = promise.then(...
```

Comment: coming back to this, this is the right solution, but I would need to write a  .catch() for each new promise, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, if you want to handle errors in all cases you would. If you don't have any meaningful error handling to perform you don't.